# Show different parts of form depending on quantity entered in field in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
              if ($('#quantity').val >= 1) {
        $( "<p>Option #1</p>" ).appendTo( "#options" );
                   $('#optionone').show();
        }
              if ($('#quantity').val >= 2) {
        $( "<p>Option #2</p>" ).appendTo( "#options" );
                   $('#optiontwo').show();        
        }
```

quantity is the id of a text field that gets submitted in my code. the above code should have worked (or so I thought) to display different texts for different values in the field but for some reason it just doesn't do anything.

Although this does work perfectly:

```
$( "<p>Option #1</p>" ).appendTo( "#options" );
$('#optionone').show();
$( "<p>Option #2</p>" ).appendTo( "#options" );
$('#optiontwo').show();
```

So obviously my condition code is wrong, but how else can I access the field value and do stuff according to the value of it?

Please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
$('#quantity').val()
```

instead of

```
$('#quantity').val
```

See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Exactly, but making the change directly broke my code. 
I had to go for var quanvalue = $('#quantity').val(); and then do if (quanvalue >= 1) and so on.